# How to make single node prediction regression model from training data of multiple graphs with PyTorch Geometric?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, data-science, pytorch-geometric

I have a dataset which contains multiple of the same graph just with different node values.

[image]

How would I create a model with PyTorch Geometric to predict a single missing value on the graph?

[image]

I was thinking of training a GCN with a random mask on an individual example but from the document action it seems that a) `Data` only expects to take one graph with a mask as a training input b) `GCN` will make predictions on an entire graph not a single node.